# What is the complex potential of a uniform flow around an ellipse?

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I have the complex potential of a uniform flow around a circle which is:

$Ω = Uz+\frac{Ua^2}{z}$

I was told that the complex potential of a uniform flow around an ellipse is:

$Ω = Uz+\frac{U(a^2+b^2)}{z}$

where $a$ is the semi-minor axis and $b$ is the semi-major axis.

Is this correct? I was wondering since I noticed that if I had an ellipse with a semi-minor axis of 3 and a semi-major axis of 4, the entire flow field would act the same as if it were a circle with radius 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Elliptic cylinder in uniform (horizontal) flow:

$$f(z)=U
\left(
  \frac{az-b\sqrt{z^2-a^2+b^2}}{a-b}
\right)$$

- Oblique flow around an elliptic cylinder:

$$f(z)=U
\left(
  \frac{z+\sqrt{z^2-a^2+b^2}}{2}
\right)+
\overline{U}
\left(
  \frac{a+b}{a-b}
\right)
\left(
  \frac{z-\sqrt{z^2-a^2+b^2}}{2}
\right)$$